# Keep getting A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-3.2, return-path

```
class SupportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "email1@gmail.com"

  def welcome_email(ticket)
    case ticket.game
    when "gameone"
        @ticket = ticket
        headers["Reply-to"] = "email1+#{ticket.token}@gmail.com"
        headers["Return-Path"] = "email1+#{ticket.token}@gmail.com"
        mail(:from => "email1@gmail.com", :to => ticket.email, :subject => "Welcome to 1 Support Ticket")
    when "gametwo"
        @ticket = ticket
        headers["Reply-to"] = "email2+#{ticket.token}@gmail.com"
        headers["Return-Path"] = "email2+#{ticket.token}@gmail.com"
        mail(:from => "email2@gmail.com", :to => ticket.email, :subject => "Welcome to 2 Support Ticket")
    when "gamethree"
        @ticket = ticket
        headers["Reply-to"] = "email3+#{ticket.token}@gmail.com"
        header["Return-Path"] = "email3+#{ticket.token}@gmail.com"
        mail(:from => "email3@gmail.com", :to => ticket.email, :subject => "Welcome to 3 Support Ticket")
    end
  end
end
```

I've set my default :from, so I don't get why I keep getting this message, I'm also trying to set it via headers to no avail.

here are my settings

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "emailx@gmail.com",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I just call it like so, `SupportMailer.support_response(@message).deliver`

How do I fix this?

Comment: The headers are definitely not needed; the code looks correct, and in your case the `default :from` is overridden by the value in the call to the `mail` method.  I would look upstream where the deliver! method is called, or perhaps in the enviroment files.  The error comes from one of the first tests after the deliver! method in the smtp module.

Comment: i've looked in my controller. it looks ok. and my configs look fine. i'll post them

Comment: I've added this line the the methods `headers "return-path" => "email1@gmail.com"` and now it is complaining about `At least one recipient (To, Cc or Bcc) is required to send a message`, it looks like `mail(...)` isn't picking up it's parameters.

Comment: Hmm -- I tested with my gmail account, with a simple example.  Perhaps I see the issue: all the recommendations I see suggest defining the configuration from one of the environment files (I put mine in `app/config/environments/development.rb` just for the test.  It started `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp`  `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {`...

Maybe this is the problem?  Otherwise, I would say: simplify -- take out everything that's not essential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice you have no default case for the case statement. If you never end up calling the "mail" method inside your methods in the Mailer class, you'll get that error. Try moving your case statement out to where you call SupportMailer, maybe have methods for each case. That way you never call the SupportMailer unless you've already determined the correct ticket game.

Comment: This is correct. Ideally pull the logic out of the mailer. If you don't want to, you can always do: `self.message.perform_deliveries = false` if you decide to abort the delivery, don't call return as it will continue the execution and throw the same error.